# AM charts plots on the wong position

Tags: angularjs, amcharts

Am charts plots lines some lines on the wrong y-axis position. see code and snapshot bellow.

My graphs:

```
[{"bullet":"none","labelsEnabled":false,"dashLength":0,"lineThickness":3,"title":[["Tonnes Milled"]],"valueField":"TonnesMilled","balloonText":"[[value]]","valueAxis":"LeftAxis","numberFormatter":{"precision":2,"decimalSeparator":".","thousandsSeparator":","},"lineColorField":"Color"},{"bullet":"none","labelsEnabled":false,"dashLength":0,"lineThickness":3,"title":[["Total Magalies Water PPM"]],"valueField":"TotalMagaliesWaterPPM","balloonText":"[[value]]","valueAxis":"LeftAxis","numberFormatter":{"precision":2,"decimalSeparator":".","thousandsSeparator":","},"lineColorField":"Color"},{"bullet":"none","labelsEnabled":false,"dashLength":0,"lineThickness":3,"title":[["Water Average Daily Consumption"]],"valueField":"WaterAverageDailyConsumption","balloonText":"[[value]]","valueAxis":"LeftAxis","numberFormatter":{"precision":2,"decimalSeparator":".","thousandsSeparator":","},"lineColorField":"Color"},{"bullet":"none","labelsEnabled":false,"dashLength":0,"lineThickness":3,"title":[["Water Consumption M3/ton"]],"valueField":"WaterConsumptionM3Ton","balloonText":"[[value]]","valueAxis":"LeftAxis","numberFormatter":{"precision":2,"decimalSeparator":".","thousandsSeparator":","},"lineColorField":"Color"}]
```

My data:

```
[{"TotalMagaliesWaterPPM":236458,"WaterAverageDailyConsumption":7627.677419354839,"WaterConsumptionM3Ton":0,"Date":"Jan - 2019","TonnesMilled":0,"DateConverted":true},{"TotalMagaliesWaterPPM":236459,"WaterAverageDailyConsumption":8444.964285714286,"WaterConsumptionM3Ton":0,"Date":"Feb - 2019","TonnesMilled":0,"DateConverted":true},{"TotalMagaliesWaterPPM":236460,"WaterAverageDailyConsumption":7627.741935483871,"WaterConsumptionM3Ton":0,"Date":"Mar - 2019","TonnesMilled":0,"DateConverted":true},{"TotalMagaliesWaterPPM":236461,"WaterAverageDailyConsumption":7882.033333333334,"WaterConsumptionM3Ton":0,"Date":"Apr - 2019","TonnesMilled":0,"DateConverted":true},{"TotalMagaliesWaterPPM":236462,"WaterAverageDailyConsumption":7627.806451612903,"WaterConsumptionM3Ton":0,"Date":"May - 2019","TonnesMilled":0,"DateConverted":true}]
```

Pay attention to the blue lines mostly:

**Sample**:

[image: sample]

**Another Sample**:

[image: another sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your date format. You try to give your dates MMM - YYYY format, but chart do not know this and and render all of them as Jan 2019. Check this:

[Formatting dates on category axis | amCharts3](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/formatting-dates/)

Comment: problem was my amChartOptions setting options. im using 1  directive dynamic directive for all my charts charts... so the  *stackType*  property which i used for stacked bar charts messes up my line chart, i have to find a way to apply this property only to my stacked bar charts without it affectin everything... im going to give you a thumbs up, thanks for your help